# EventListener scroll и height 100%

Tags: javascript, css, события

У меня есть 2 блока высотой по 50%
Хочу  добавить `addEventListener('scroll', func)` но скролл не срабатывает из за того что (как я понимаю) у `body` и `html` установлен `height: 100%`.
Я хочу сделать у себя подобие FullPage Scroll, а значит мне нужны и `height: 100%` и работающий event scroll.
Как это реализовать?
Без подключения сторонних плагинов

Comment: передавайте func без (), тоесть без вызова, ссылку на функцию

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это я тут поторопился просто... в коде я правильно указал addEventListener, и если отключить подключение стилей он срабатывал. Поэтому проблема именно в отключении скролла когда высота у html и body 100%

Comment: а Вам обязательно что бы скроллбар не был виден?

Comment: @Август немного не понял вопроса...  Я просто хочу отловить событие при скролле страницы, но как я понял (гуглил) - это событие отключается когда установлена 100% высота body

Comment: scroll должен срабатывать, добавьте сниппет, демонстрирующий проблему

Comment: @StrangerintheQ

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
    console.log('hello')
})

Срабатывает когда убираю css стили в хедере.
А с подключенными стилями нет

Comment: @HaZcker, **scrollbar** - это полоска скролла в браузере. теоретически, Вы бы могли добавить **+1px** к 100% высоте страницы и событие `scroll` работало, так как было бы куда скроллить (**1px** вверх и потом **1px** вниз). но минус этого *костыля* - наличие этого скроллбара, который бы портил эстетический вид сайта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я Вас понял.
используйте событие `wheel`. в отличии от `scroll`, он срабатывает всегда, даже если странице негде скролиться. **НО** не будет работать на телефонах, так как там нет *мышки*